# How do I install a program from terminal with no errors?

Tags: 11.10, command-line

Whenever I try to install something through terminal, I try to do it the same way I did it last time. Let's say the program "Samba" here is what I do:
sudo apt-get install "samba"
It says that their is no such package! What's going on? Did I type something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use quotes.  You might want to make sure everything is updated and upgraded first too.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Comment: how about something with spaces? Do I use quotes then?

Comment: What has spaces?  Package names don't contain spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your package cache is out of date. Please try the following command first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The quotes around "samba" are not necessary unless the package name contains spaces (what should never be the case), but using quotes should be no problem.

If it doesn't work after this command line, please read the output from this command. Maybe you have an error in your package sources definition file (/etc/apt/sources.list) - sometimes this is caused by adding a malformed PPA line or by editing this file manually. You can set a line to *ignore* by prepending a #. Another possibility could be the opposite of the above - if an important line is set to *ignore*. After editing the sources.list, you *must* do the update - command line before installing.